# Is a nonzero linear functional is not constant on each ball?

Tags: analysis

Let $T$ be a nonzero linear functional on a normed space $X$. 
Is it then true that on each ball $B(x,r)$, $f$ is not constant?

Comment: Yes (for $r>0$).

Comment: Why (for $r>0$)?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can consider for the sake of clarity $B(0,r)$. Take $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $||x_1||,||x_2|| < \frac{r}{4}$ and $T(x_1) \neq 0$ $T(x_2) \neq 0$ (these elements exist because $T$ is nonzero), then $||x_1+x_2||<r$, so $x_1+x_2 \in B(0,r)$.

Now apply $T$ to the new element:

$$T(x_1+x_2) = T(x_1) + T(x_2) \neq T(x_1)$$

So the functional is not constant. The argument holds for any ball of radius r composing with a translation.

Comment: If you use translations you should probably prove the statement for $B(o,r)$ and affine nonconstant mapping,

Comment: Yes, the argument is exactly the same as the proposed.